# Scroll DataTable's parent when reach the top/bottom

Tags: flutter, vertical-scrolling

I have a `DataTable2` widget inside a column. When the scrolling reaches to the bottom (or to the top) I would like the parent to scroll to.
The `DataTable2` widget has some default scrolling mechanism inside, so I can't remove the scrolling.

While scrolling this up touching inside the table, I would like the whole page to go up.

[image]

This is the code

```
Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("Leaderboard", style: TextPalette.h1Default)
                    ]),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: ButtonTheme(
                          alignedDropdown: true,
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            isDense: true,
                            elevation: 1,
                            value: selectedLeaderboard,
                            items: leaderboardNameToId.entries
                                .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: e.key, child: Text(e.key)))
                                .toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 16),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Palette.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: ButtonTheme(
                          alignedDropdown: true,
                          child: DropdownButton<int>(
                            isDense: true,
                            value: sortColumnIndex,
                            elevation: 1,
                            items: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                                .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                                    value: e, child: Text(sortableColumns[e])))
                                .toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                if (leaderboard != null)
                  InfoContainer(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 16,
                          top: 16, bottom: 16),
                      child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        child: DataTable2(
                            sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                            sortAscending: sortAscending,
                            dataRowHeight: 36,
                            headingRowHeight: 36,
                            columnSpacing: 4,
                            smRatio: 0.55,
                            dividerThickness: 0,
                            horizontalMargin: 0,
                            columns: [
                              DataColumn2(
                                fixedWidth: 20,
                                label: Text('', style: TextPalette.h3),
                              ),
                              DataColumn2(
                                  label: Text('NAME', style: TextPalette.h3),
                                  size: ColumnSize.M),
                              DataColumn2(
                                  size: ColumnSize.S,
                                  label: Text('SCORE', style: TextPalette.h3),
                                  tooltip: "Average score",
                                  numeric: true),
                              DataColumn2(
                                  size: ColumnSize.S,
                                  label: Text('POTM', style: TextPalette.h3),
                                  numeric: true,
                                  tooltip:
                                      "Number of Player of the Match awards"),
                              DataColumn2(
                                  size: ColumnSize.S,
                                  label: Text('MATCH', style: TextPalette.h3),
                                  numeric: true),
                              DataColumn2(
                                  size: ColumnSize.S,
                                  label: Text('WIN %', style: TextPalette.h3),
                                  numeric: true,
                                  tooltip: "Percentage of games won"),
                            ],
                            rows: leaderboard!.entries
                                .asMap()
                                .entries
                                .map((entry) => DataRow(cells: [
                                      DataCell(Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                        child: Text(
                                          (entry.key + 1).toString(),
                                          style: TextPalette.getBodyText(
                                              Palette.greyLight),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                      DataCell(Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              UserAvatar(
                                                  10.0,
                                                  context
                                                      .watch<UserState>()
                                                      .getUserDetail(
                                                          entry.value.userId)),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 4,
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Align(
                                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                                  child: UserNameWidget(
                                                      userDetails: context
                                                          .watch<UserState>()
                                                          .getUserDetail(entry
                                                              .value.userId)),
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ))),
                                      DataCell(Text(
                                          entry.value.averageScore
                                                  ?.toStringAsFixed(2) ??
                                              "-",
                                          style: TextPalette.getBodyText(
                                              Palette.black))),
                                      DataCell(Text(
                                          entry.value.potmCount.toString(),
                                          style: TextPalette.getBodyText(
                                              Palette.black))),
                                      DataCell(Text(
                                          entry.value.numMatchesJoined.toString(),
                                          style: TextPalette.getBodyText(
                                              Palette.black))),
                                      DataCell(Text(
                                          entry.value
                                                  .getWinLossRatio()
                                                  ?.toStringAsFixed(0) ??
                                              "-",
                                          style: TextPalette.getBodyText(
                                              Palette.black))),
                                    ]))
                                .toList()),
                      )),
                if (leaderboard == null)
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 36),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                          width: 26,
                          height: 26,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              strokeWidth: 3,
                              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                  Palette.primary))),
                    ),
                  )
              ],
            ),
```